# Observer Design Pattern on different Cores say (Observer and Subject as separte processes) ( C++ )

Tags: c++, centos7, observer-pattern

I have tried as per my level but no success. Have read also blogs but not leading me to the correct solution.

My requirement is based on Observer Design Pattern, where Subject (or Publisher) would be running continuously on say CORE no .1 of Machine / Server and generating some random numbers for "temperature, humidity and  pressure".

Now I want to start a process (say Observer / Subscriber) on another core say Core No. 5, which will at any given point of time try to register itself to the Subject or Publisher for seeing recently generated numbers for "temperature, humidity and pressure" from the Subject / Publisher and then immediately after publishing, it shall start getting updates from Subject / Publisher.

*What I have done is follows:*

**a)** Created a Class Subject having registerObserver, deregisterObserver, and notifyObservers as methods, it also has noOfObservers as attribute, so that once the registration happens, it gets increased by one ..

**b)** Create a interface class Observer having method update (float temp, float humidity, float pressure)

**c)** Create a WeatherData Class derived from Subject (having register, deregister.. methods). This has a method called **changeState(float temp, float humidity, float pressure)** which calls notifyObservers from Subject Class (as Subject Class is supposed to have all registered Observers).

**d)** Application weather.cpp which creates an Object of Class WeatherData generates random numbers and call changeState () with temp, humidity and pressure. This will run on one specific core no. 1 of the machine

**e) On Client / Observer / Subscriber side** : I create a programm client.cpp which creates an instance of Client-Class which is derived from interface Observer and call the static method of Subject Class as follows:
**Subject::registerObserver(cltptr);**

I have done some cout statement to show, if this registering happens at all on other core. To see this i just increment the counter by 1 every time registerObserver is called.

However, it seems it is not possible to run the applications of WeatherStation (Subject / Publisher) and Client ( Observer / Subscriber) on different Cores independently.

If some Guru has done such thing already and would help me getting this correct, so that Weatherstation and Client can run separately, I would greatful to him/her.

Main idea is to run Observer and Subject on different cores and still able to communicate with each other. For me Push/Pull /Callback anything will work which is little bit optimised. Idea is to get this working in someway on different cores separately.

In Internet most examples are for everything on one core, threads etc, which is not the case with me currently.

***Thanks for all the Help in advance.***

Sample Code is as follows what i tried:

```
**------------------------------weather.cpp----------------------------------**
// ------------------------ This is the WeatherStation / Subject / Publisher --!
#include <iostream>
#include "ifobserver.h"
#include "ifsubject.h"
#include "weather.h"
#include <unistd.h>

float randomnumber(float limit) {
/* return a random number between 0 and limit inclusive.
*/
   float divisor = RAND_MAX/(limit+1);
   float retval;
   do {
       retval = rand() / divisor;
   } while (retval > limit);
   return retval;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

   float temp = 16;
   float humidity = 30.2;
   float pressure = 2.9;

WeatherData weatherStation; // just like platform...

int lookups = 0;

while(true)  // unlimited loop for weather changes...
{
   temp     = randomnumber(45.0);
   humidity = randomnumber(80.0);
   pressure = randomnumber(9);

   weatherStation.changeState(temp, humidity, pressure); // this sill nofity all Observers...
   ++lookups;
   usleep(200000); // 200 milliseconds..
   if(lookups>= 50000)
    { std::cout << "All cycles ended" << std::endl;
    return false;
    }
}

   return 0;
}

**------------------------------weather.h----------------------------------**
#ifndef WEATHER_H_
#define WEATHER_H_

#include "ifobserver.h"
#include "ifsubject.h"
#include <iostream>

// Specific implementation of Subject Interface...

class WeatherData : public Subject {

   float temp = 0.0f;
   float humidity = 0.0f;
   float pressure = 0.0f;

   public:
       /**
            * Set the new state of the weather station
            * @param temp new temperature
            * @param humidity new humidity
            * @param pressure new pressure
            */
           void changeState(float temp, float humidity, float pressure)
           {
               this->temp = temp;
               this->humidity = humidity;
               this->pressure = pressure;
               std::cout << "New-Temp , Humidtiy, Pressure=" << this->temp << "," <<  this->humidity << "," << this->pressure
                         <<  "....registerd Observers = " << noOfObservers << std::endl;

               notifyObservers(temp, humidity, pressure);

           }
};

#endif /* WEATHER_H_ */


**------------------------------ifobserver.h----------------------------------**

#ifndef IFOBSERVER_H_
#define IFOBSERVER_H_
/**
* Interface for the Observer
*/
class Observer {

public:

   /**
    * Update the state of this observer
    * @param temp new temperaure
    * @param humidity new humidity
    * @param pressure new pressure
    */
   virtual void update(float temp, float humidity, float pressure) = 0;

   virtual ~Observer() {}

};

#endif /* IFOBSERVER_H_ */


**------------------------------ifsubject.h----------------------------------**

#ifndef IFSUBJECT_H_
#define IFSUBJECT_H_

#include "ifobserver.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Subject {

protected :

   inline static int noOfObservers;

public:

   Subject() {
       std::cout << "Constructor()" << std::endl;
   }

   static void registerObserver(const Observer *observer)  {
       ++noOfObservers;
       std::cout << "registerObserver() - called: Address=" << observer << ", No-of-subcribers" << noOfObservers << std::endl;

       }

   static inline void deregisterObserver(const Observer *observer) {
   //      // to remove first, we have to find them and then remove
   ////        auto itr = std::find(observers.begin( ), observers.end( ), observer);
   ////
   ////        if (itr != observers.end())
   ////            observers.erase(itr);

       std::cout << "deregisterObserver() - called: Address=" << observer << std::endl;
       }


   static void notifyObservers(float& temp, float& humidity, float& pressure) {

       if (noOfObservers <= 0)
      return;
       std::cout << "notifyObservers() - called =" << temp << "," << humidity << "," << pressure << std::endl;

}



};

**------------------------------client.h----------------------------------**
#ifndef CLIENT_H_
#define CLIENT_H_

#include "ifobserver.h"
#include <iostream>

class Client : public Observer {

int id;

public:

Client(int& id) : id(id) { std::cout << "Client-No:" << id << "created" << std::endl;}

void update(float temp, float humidity, float pressure)
{
   std::cout << "Temp , Humidtiy, Pressure=" << temp << "," <<  humidity << "," << pressure << std::endl;
}

};

#endif /* CLIENT_H_ */

// ------**********************************************************--------------//
**------------------------------client.cpp----------------------------------**
// This is the Client, which tries to register itself to the Publisher to get weather updates on separate Cores..
#include <iostream>
#include "client.h"
#include "ifsubject.h"
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

int i = 0;

Client * clptr[20];

while (i < 20)
{

   clptr[i] = new Client(i);
   Subject::registerObserver(clptr[i]);

   usleep(500000);
++i;
}

// delete memory
for( int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
   delete clptr[i];
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: All this talk of "cores" seems to indicate a fundamental misunderstanding of how modern operating systems handle processes and threads. If you mean "they're just different processes" then say that.

Comment: Please indicate which OS / Platform are you using, added as as a tag to your question.

Comment: Does this boil down to "How can I implement the Observer pattern when the data being observed is in another process?" If so the answer is you need some kind of Inter-Process Communication (IPC) to convey the changes in state to the observers.

Comment: Instead of throw all your source code here, you should split your problem. What is not working? You are not able to communicate between processes? Then ask about this topic without wasting with all your data structures which are fully independent to this problem. If you need better data structures, ask about that! But please throw an endless listing which is more or less unrelated to your problem! Thanks!